# Ionic 3 image local application folder not showing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have downloaded some images to my app. They get stored in the application directory. This is one of the urls:

```
file:///Users/w3/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CE0C21C3-2A3C-4C2F-AFF5-3A034A17F1EC/data/Containers/Data/Application/45AC6BC6-B8C2-433C-8E6C-3356EFAEB2B2/Library/NoCloud/WinGD%20Low-speed%20Engines%202017.jpg
```

If I paste this link into any browser the image shows fine. When placing it into an image tag inside my view, the image does not show. Changing the path to a wrong path shows the questionmark icon for not found. So the image should gets found by the device.

```
<img class="brochure" src='file:///Users/w3/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/CE0C21C3-2A3C-4C2F-AFF5-3A034A17F1EC/data/Containers/Data/Application/304605E4-72D7-4C0F-9027-E46EC0C76C1E/Library/NoCloud/test.png'>
```

I have tried it with [src] and various additions to my config.xml

```
<allow-intent href="file:*" />
<access origin="file://*" />
```

and my index.html file.

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

No change. I´m testing on an ios11 emulator + on my physical device. 
Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

I'm getting the filepath like (with cordova-plugin-file):

```
this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(this.file.dataDirectory+"test.png").then(result => {
   console.log("beforeresult:"+this.file.dataDirectory + "test.png")
   console.log("result"+result.nativeURL)
   return result.nativeURL;
}, error =>{
   return JSON.stringify(error);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using wkwebview, you can follow these steps:

```
import { normalizeURL} from 'ionic-angular';
```

Store your image path in some new variable.

```
var imagePath = this.file.dataDirectory + "test.png";
this.tempImagePath = normalizeURL(imagePath);
```

Then in your html file, just use tempImagePath as image src.

The change is described here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/

Comment: Strangely when saving/copying photos using CordovaFile, I need to keep the file:// part of the directory path BUT displaying the image in the view requires you to remove the file:// from the path.  Not very clear and took a while for me to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

If those images are static files, then you need to put them in the assets folder and reference them with a relative path. if you need your app to by able to reach the storage, you need to install a [cordova plugin as explained here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file)

Comment: I need to get access to files stored on the device. I have installed cordova-plugin-file. This plugin gave me the URL to the image inside the application folder

Answer (score 1):

Sanitize the URL before using it:

```
import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

public displayImage: SafeUrl;
...
constructor( private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, .... ) {}
...

prepareImage(imageData)
{
    if(imageData!= null)
    {

        this.displayImage = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageData);
    }
}
```

In template:

```
<img [src]="displayImage">
```

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your path like this.

The problem with file:/// just replace with file://

```
this.ImageData = imagePath.replace(/^file:\/\//, '');
```

Comment: Nothing changed. When I try to paste the URL into the browser with 2 instead of 3 slashed the file gets not found. With file:/// it is found. Strange.